# Unable to deploy on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After building a dotnet app from azure devops i tried to deploy the artifacts generated. But the server returned an error saying that the config data is invalid. Can someone please suggest a solution. I have attached the error screenshot.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSFtf.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NOoT.png)

Comment: Is there any special tag you used in `web.config`? Keep in mind that the final server must install out-of-band components (like URL Rewrite module) if `web.config` uses such.

Comment: Did you check the deployed web.config file in the server?

Answer (score -1):

Your web.config is invalid. Check your web.config syntax with for example Notepad++ and select Language -> XML. Perhaps you have a typo.

Comment: Checked for typo. It wasn't the issue. Working now, I needed to install ASP.NET Core Module in IIS. Thanks.

Comment: Please add you fix as an answer and then mark it as the answer, helps future visitors!